# Word for numbers with special meaning (particularly Bible)

Tags: single-word-requests

Numbers in the Biblical text often have archetypal meanings. For instance, 40 is a cycle (40 days of the Flood to wipe out the world, 40 years traveling in the desert to wipe out the prior generation of Israelites, etc.). There is a word for these representative, archetypal numbers in the Bible but it is currently alluding me.

Comment: THE BIBLICAL EXPRESSION “40 DAYS AND 40 NIGHTS” JUST MEANS A “REALLY LONG TIME” http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/08/the-biblical-expression-40-days-and-40-nights-just-means-a-really-long-time/

Comment: You may be thinking of the term "gematria," which is the study of the hidden meanings of Biblical numbers.

Comment: The common word is [*numerology*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/numerology), which is what most people would think of. But it's unclear if you are looking for a word that is specific *only* to the Bible and nothing else. (Incidentally, [*gematria*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gematria) seems to apply to Hebrew scriptures, not necessarily—or especially only—to the Bible.)

Answer (score 2):

After more searching, I believe the technical term is '[typological](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=BImK1cN04pwC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22typological%20number%22&source=bl&ots=lTKmjCC46E&sig=ACfU3U0A9D0mFwV9lUJVBEXyT6FBQR9fFw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3i5SmqczpAhWSqqQKHRpCChgQ6AEwCXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22typological%20number%22&f=false) number', '[archetypal](http://faculty.history.umd.edu/BCooperman/NewCity/Jerusalem.html) number', or '[formulaic](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=S75SDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT74&lpg=PT74&dq=%22formulaic%20%20number%22%20bible&source=bl&ots=gs_zxmYmuV&sig=ACfU3U08-micjtsfHBwu_dOohEP-tdt6-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4pP7JrMzpAhXB2KQKHfeMAZkQ6AEwAXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22formulaic%20%20number%22%20bible&f=false) number'. Though 'typological' has [additional meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typology_(theology)) when relating to Christian theology and the relationship of the New and Old Testaments.

Comment: They're uncommon strings in Google searches. I'm not sure whether these terms merit 'standard' classification.

Comment: The knowledge domain is relatively niche (Biblical literary analysis), so I wouldn't expect the general internet to accurately reflect the appropriateness of such specialized words. A search on Google Scholar returns ~100 results for each term which seems respectable. Would be glad to compare these terms to other potential candidates with similar usages.

Comment: Yes, they're better (and so is the question if it requests 'typological number') on say Christianity.SE (there is a 'terminology' tag there).